# actionmailer works in console but not in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, rails-api, rails-console

I am using action mailer in a production heroku environment.  When I run the console like so:

```
heroku run console
FamilyMailer.notify_family_member(FamilyMember.last)
```

It works perfectly and sends the email.  However, when I write the EXACT SAME line in a controller, It doesn't seem to activate the mailer. The `puts` statement in the mailer doesn't even appear in the console. Here is the controller action:

```
def create
  puts "in the create action"
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @event.notify_family_members  #from Event model called below
end
```

Here is the event model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    def notify_family_members
        puts "in model method"
        FamilyMailer.notify_family_member(FamilyMember.last)
    end
end
```

Here is the mailer:

```
class FamilyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "Gold<contact@goldyo.me>"
  def notify_family_member(family_member)
    puts "in the mailer"
    mail(to: family_member.email, subject: "Photos").deliver
  end
end
```

Here are the server logs:

```
2016-04-26T20:00:07.110616+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/api/events" for 69.46.236.36 at 2016-04-26 20:00:07 +0000
2016-04-26T20:00:07.231857+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Api::EventsController#create as HTML
2016-04-26T20:00:07.231967+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"event_id"=>7, "event_attendees"=>{"1"=>"Larry Ellison"}, "event"=>{}}
2016-04-26T20:00:07.242261+00:00 app[web.1]: in the create action
2016-04-26T20:00:07.444983+00:00 app[web.1]: in model method
2016-04-26T20:00:07.462242+00:00 app[web.1]: [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Event (0.81ms)
2016-04-26T20:00:07.463231+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 231ms (Views: 9.4ms | ActiveRecord: 26.9ms)
2016-04-26T20:00:07.462845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/events" host=goldenowl.herokuapp.com request_id=d6aeb940-a65a-4667-be1c-263bee9ef899 fwd="69.46.236.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=359ms status=200 bytes=824
```

As you can see, the model method is being called but the mailer is just being ignored.  I've also tried changing `.deliver` to `.deliver_now` but that does not help.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `deliver` method, should be called at the Mailer method. But instead of using `deliver`, use `deliver_now` or `deliver_later`.

Change your controller to:

```
def create
    FamilyMailer.notify_family_member(FamilyMember.last).deliver_now
end
```

And your mailer:

```
class FamilyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "Gold<contact@goldyo.me>"
  def notify_family_member(family_member)
    puts "in the mailer"
    mail(to: family_member.email, subject: "Photos")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything.  The mailer is still not being called.

Comment: @Philip7899 are you sure you are calling the `create` method?

Comment: @Philip7899 this happens locally too or only on heroku?

Comment: OK, it turns out your code ended up working!  But I don't understand -- why won't deliver work if included inside the mailer?